# Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Although I am by no means an expert on Ubuntu, I have had two servers running for a couple of years with no problems.

Last night, when attempting to access a local website on one of them I got the error:

```
**Bad Request**
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

After several hours of frustration and no success, I rebuilt the server.  While Ubuntu was installing I went to the other server and got the exact same error.
The first server has now been rebuilt and it displays the same error.

I have shut down every computer on the network.  Powered down the router and started over.

In addition to the two servers, the network consists of three windows machines and a Ubuntu desktop.

I have tried isolating the machines from the Internet, I have tried both wired and wireless clients.

Going to localhost on the servers displays the Ubuntu Apache Default page.

The only thing that happened about the time the problem started was the Windows decided to shutdown this machine for an update.  I don't see how this could have caused a problem but I have isolated this machine from the network and the problem exists.

I cleared cookies, used five different browsers, and they all report the same error. I'm about out of ideas, and looking for any suggestions.

Comment: I failed to mention that there is nothing in the Apache error logs for either machine.

Comment: How do you access the servers from the local network? IP? DNS? If so, which one? Getting the default page on the server itself means Apache is not the culprit but it would be interesting to test the real vhost you're trying to access. Has your DNS been hijacked and you're not taping into your local servers at all but everything gets sent somewhere else? Worth investigating.

Comment: All are accessed via "local names" in the hosts file dor example

Comment: Verify the hosts files didn't change and try to access the same hostname from the servers themselves (that would point to localhost on the server, but still go to the correct vhost).

Comment: Also try with another router, it might be failing and mangles the packets on the network.

Comment: Host names have not changed.  Accessing the vhost from the server results in the same error.  I have removed the router completely and the problem remained.  Also tried a different switch with no luck.

Comment: So the issue is with the vhost, that's good to know. Try to increase Apache's log level from `warn` to `debug` and see if you can track the errors down. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel

Comment: Here is what the error log reports.  I don't really understand it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144018/discussion-between-dave-davis-and-capsule).

Answer (score 93):

In my case, it's actually the underscore **`_`** in DocumentRoot that causes problem and hours of debugging. All work fine once I remove it from my DocumentRoot path.

Comment: i am having same issue. do you know why apache react like this on "_" ?

Comment: @chudasamachirag i don't know why Apache behave like that.

Comment: I have changed "_" to "-" in ServerName, ServerAlias, VirtualHost and it works! Thanks for this hint!

Comment: For me it was enought to change the ServerName so that it would not have underscore. Apache should write in the error message that underscore is not supported in ServerName. It should really not waste hours of developers time for this, I am lucky that I found this post. I am using windows 7

Comment: Does anyone know why this error doesn't show up in the log files?

Comment: @Darius.V me too. Just the ServerName

Comment: Same problem, but in ServerName/ServerAlias - underscore in subdomain.
Related link: https://ma.ttias.be/apache-httpd-2-2-15-60-underscores-hostnames-now-blocked/

Answer (score 29):

This is due to the update RFC 3986, which claims that underscores are unsafe in virtual host servernames and other elements. In my case, I could not change the URL name, so I just allowed this underscores by enabling these unsafe urls. To do that, just add `HttpProtocolOptions unsafe` to the httpd.conf file.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#httpprotocoloptions

Comment: I was wondering how my frontends were suddenly getting that error after I moved my backend from Docker's php5.6-apache official image to php7.1-apache, thanks :) (note that my services name url had an underscore in them)

Answer (score 10):

For newer httpd versions do not support Hyphens in the URL in that case you have to add HttpProtocolOptions unsafe to the httpd.conf file, it works fine after that.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, I'm 99.99% sure I have found the problem with the help of *Capsule*. The key to success was changing Apache's error level to debug.  This gave me a starting point and from there a bit of trial and error and all was well.

I had two servers B777 and B767 which I used for local development.  for development websites I used something like www.something.767 and www.something.777.  All of the sites were listed in a hosts file.

For several years this worked just fine.  For some reason I may never understand, last evening, I began to get the aforementioned error on both servers and on another I built this evening.

**It seems that the problem was using numbers in the domain name.**  As soon as I changed a domain name from www.something.767 to www.something.local (or apparently any other non numeric characters) everything was back to normal.

Comment: Exactly same thing happened with me while doing drupal multi site setup. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove the underscore (`_`) from the `ServerName` directive, as well as the hostname in `/etc/hosts`.

However, the underscore in `DocumentRoot` is just fine.

Thus, the relevant line in `/etc/hosts` looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       mycoolsite.localhost
```

And the relevant block in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/satoshi/Sites/my_cool_site"
    ServerName mycoolsite.localhost
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/my_cool_site.localhost-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/my_cool_site.localhost-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to run `apachectl restart` after making your changes.

Comment: I just faced the same problem right now. Spent an hour trying to find out what was wrong, and the moment I removed the underscore it started working. Weird :/ any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I have not dealt with the issue since then (nearly two years).

Answer (score 2):

In Docker Compose, if you use the networking that allows you to use container names as urls/hosts to communicate back and forth, you need to make sure you don't use underscores in the name (per [Nero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44920985/5937428)).

This took me forever to debug, so I'm including the initial error text below (again) so that hopefully Google serves this question a little higher to the next person trying to fix php curl on a docker network.

> 400 Bad Request Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>
> Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 1):

This error haunted me for days, untill I finally got it.

In my case, I was making a CURL to an URL that has an empty space at the end. Can you believe it? Removing the space was enough to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue what that the upstream backend definition of the Nginx server contains an underscore. It was hard for me to detect because `centos1` and `centos` were remote hosts running Nginx servers whereas the last server is `localhost` httpd server. The two remote servers were load-balancing fine, but not the last which makes it difficult to figure out that it was the `_` underscore that is the issue.

**Before**

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://server_group;
}
```

```
upstream server_group {
        server centos1;
        server centos2;
        server localhost:8085;

}
```

**After**

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://servergroup;
}
```

```
upstream servergroup {
        server centos1;
        server centos2;
        server localhost:8085;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Microsoft identity. In my case, user claims in table claims in db was very high. The user's problem was solved when I deleted the user's claims in the table and cleared the cookie in user browser.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31240104)

Comment: I found that if you use Microsoft Identity for authentication and have a large cookie, this is derived from the claim. In my case, this generate 'Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand' error. do you think this is unrelated to question?

Answer (score -1):

Try check your URL again. Could be missing slash. :-)